# Apache Spark: Apply existing mllib model on Incoming DStreams/DataFrames

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

Using Apache Spark's mllib, I have a Logistic Regression model that I store in HDFS. This Logistic Regression model is trained on historical data coming in from some sensors.

I have another spark program that consumes streaming data from these sensors. I want to be able to use the pre-existing trained model to do predictions on incoming data stream. Note: I don't want my model to be updated by this data.

To load the training model, I'd have to use the following line in my code:

```
val logisticModel = LogisticRegressionModel.load(sc, <location of model>)
```

sc: spark context.

However, this application is a streaming application and hence already has a "StreamingContext" setup. Now, from what I've read, it is bad practice to have two contexts in the same program (even though it is possible).

Does this mean that my approach is wrong and I can't do what I'm trying to ?

Also, would it make more sense if I keep storing the stream data in a file and keep running logistic regression on that rather than trying to do it directly in the streaming application ?

Comment: Were you able to load and use the model in the streaming context? When I use predict function in the streaming context, it throws serialization exception. I am using Spark 1.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StreamingContext` can created in a few ways including two constructors which take an existing `SparkContext`:

- `StreamingContext(path: String, sparkContext: SparkContext)` - where `path` is a path to a checkpoint file
- `StreamingContext(sparkContext: SparkContext, batchDuration: Duration)`

So you can simply create `SparkContext`, load required models, and create `StreamingContext`:

```
val sc: SparkContext = ???
...
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
```

You can also get `SparkContext` using `StreamingContext.sparkContext` method:

```
val ssc: StreamingContext  = ???
ssc.sparkContext: SparkContext
```

Comment: StreamingContext.sparkContext was an excellent idea ! thanks a lot !